# HTML/CSS Rendering on GeckoWebBrowser local development system and Deployed server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, emulation, gecko, geckofx

I used GeckoWebrowser control in my VB.Net desktop application by following this [link](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?692005-Mozilla-Firefox-Gecko-Xulrunner-in-VB-NET-%28versions-14-and-up%29) . 
It is working fine, but the problem is about proper rendering of CSS and HTML. When I navigate browser to local installed IIS application like:

```
              GeckoWebbrowser1.Navigate("Localhost:8081").
```

The website renders completely and works fine, BUT the same website is not rendering properly when I called it from domain:

```
        GeckoWebbrowser1.Navigate("124.25.54.50:8545").
```

Please help me how to resolve the problem. I tried every where but failed. 
Below is my Code:

```
      .grdarea1
      {
       float: none;
/*height: 30px;*/
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 0px;
margin: 0 0 0 10px;
padding: 2px 0;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-align :left ;
border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
border: #0e2a3f solid 1px;
 color: #FFFFFF;
box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
background: #4d73a0;
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4d73a0 0%, #36639c 3%, #34619a 7%, #3060a0 10%, #2c5c9a 20%, #2d588b 30%, #284f86 47%, #234573 67%, #1b3a68 90%, #1d3c6a 93%, #1c3959 97%, #1d3a5a 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #4d73a0), color-stop(3%, #36639c), color-stop(7%, #34619a), color-stop(10%, #3060a0), color-stop(20%, #2c5c9a), color-stop(30%, #2d588b), color-stop(47%, #284f86), color-stop(67%, #234573), color-stop(90%, #1b3a68), color-stop(93%, #1d3c6a), color-stop(97%, #1c3959), color-stop(100%, #1d3a5a));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4d73a0 0%, #36639c 3%, #34619a 7%, #3060a0 10%, #2c5c9a 20%, #2d588b 30%, #284f86 47%, #234573 67%, #1b3a68 90%, #1d3c6a 93%, #1c3959 97%, #1d3a5a 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4d73a0 0%, #36639c 3%, #34619a 7%, #3060a0 10%, #2c5c9a 20%, #2d588b 30%, #284f86 47%, #234573 67%, #1b3a68 90%, #1d3c6a 93%, #1c3959 97%, #1d3a5a 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4d73a0 0%, #36639c 3%, #34619a 7%, #3060a0 10%, #2c5c9a 20%, #2d588b 30%, #284f86 47%, #234573 67%, #1b3a68 90%, #1d3c6a 93%, #1c3959 97%, #1d3a5a 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4d73a0 0%, #36639c 3%, #34619a 7%, #3060a0 10%, #2c5c9a 20%, #2d588b 30%, #284f86 47%, #234573 67%, #1b3a68 90%, #1d3c6a 93%, #1c3959 97%, #1d3a5a 100%);
```

}

Comment: the problem is not on the geckowebbrowser , but its on your CSS/HTML Scripting ! post the css file or code with a new question

Comment: @K3rnel31 i added some css code. Plz help me.

Comment: do you use that as an external css file or directly on <head> tags ?

Comment: post how u declare the css

Comment: is your server ON/up ? cause i cant reslove the "124.25.54.50:8545" ???

Comment: I am using css file in a directory.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47389/discussion-between-zahidkakar-and-k3rnel31)